# "bless you!" alternative

Tags: expressions

Is there any neutral alternative the expression "bless you!"?

In other languages you can just use "health" ("salud" in Spanish and "Gesundheit" in German, for instance.

So I'd like to be polite in English without renouncing my atheism.

Comment: "Gesundheit" is commonly used among English speakers, at least in the US. Are you specifically only looking for a word of English origin?

Comment: I'm not aware that there is any _obligation_ to say anything. I wasn't brought up to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly enough, in the US the German expression is often used and is well understood.

> **gesundheit** *interj*
>   Used to wish good health to a person who has just sneezed.
>   <sub>[TMD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gesundheit)</sub>

Comment: Pretty widely used/understood in the UK, as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative. But the term no longer has any real religious significance, just as the exclamation “Christ!” no longer has that kind of significance. Saying it does not erode at your atheism. I say it, and I’m a committed atheist.

Comment: IIRC, people once said “bless you” because they believed that the devil could enter a person’s body at the moment of a sneeze, and that blessing the sneezer would protect them from demonic possession. So in using this expression, you are also mildly mocking the believers.